# Qt Gui Application deployment

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, shared-libraries

I have built a GUI application using QT Creator.
I want to deploy this application in my friend's computer. He runs Ubuntu.
To run this application I don't want to install any of the development tools in his machine like Qt Creator. I just want to install the  qt libraries.

If I do this will the application work?

Comment: You need to cros--compile your application for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to statically link the libraries with your application before deployment. That way all the necessary libraries are included in your executable!

This may help you out: http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building_static_applications

Comment: If I link the library statically I will be violating the LGPL license as I am not planning on making my application's source code open

Comment: Then why are you using QT in the first place?